# Is it possible to create a conditional type based on a literal array type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm wondering if it's possible to create a conditional type based on if a value is in an array of literal values:

```js
export type UseTablePlugins = "search" | "pagination";

function useTable<Plugins extends UseTablePlugins[]>(plugins: Plugins) {
  ...
  
  // This is the part I'm stuck on
  return searchState: Plugins extend "search"[] ? [string, Dispatch] : never;
}
```

I know TypeScript goes away on runtime and therefore is unable to find the values of variables, but I'm wondering if I do something like `useTable(["search"])` if TypeScript will understand that `search` is in the type? I hope I'm making sense :).

EDIT: Here is a [minimal example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDeBXAZyQGUYUYlsARYAsctAC22KRlPKQEENgIA7AL5wAZlAgg4AIiioMUgNwBYAFCqkAD0iw4MAJ5gkcAKpEAKigBGAGyQAFa3gDmwfgTgBeaURRQmUuAAfaXoXfnI+fkVVVRE8fl4BOEIkCxskAB4HZ1d3TQp+ABN3U1SrW2ywggBtAF0APgAKMEcqgC44StyASlxVODg0AQJ4Hz9GcqMvFpy3ADpXNEdCpAJGqTH-buU1FQGht1HUcY4KTzhNifS4AH5kolOkdalejv48a2sdgYB6H7gzIxaHBgTBGEZ6DoAJIAckkIzwaAA1nABP04LIYHgoPwLscmI84Ch3PwkAA3JBQInuLpuOD5JBFdwbfGMKR1W5waojKCuJzUWj0GBMDKsdhkCg8GCRDI8vn1eq1OBvD5fVSCGK7A4jAGTDrIdAwOYAMQAwhkcIJ6udGr0PNacOi-nAyb5gJMLowIB9CnBLEZ9IZfdyYLz+Py4DQ6AxGKK2I8pTK5eGFbV0dr4NzWVD+GA8Fg8exs7n80qvCk0rZGtUWb5-LVtprfv9XbyPQQvT6-QGDEhfe9PunhqNO9ZCgAhJAAOVV5wrk2rDe+g2Hnu9Y641gIEEnM8+c-MC5roVcEQEUiXTYxbGxuMa6IGGVcefgrscSA8OEuOZfwha6CQL0x0pDwpFYOs2VRfhTQmcMPxwRokDta0iCLCCf3zRC5jIKAnDYOY3zwJDhB+ep0W6dUgA) on TS playground.

Comment: What is `searchState`? What is `Dispatch`? Why would you want to return a value of type `never`?  Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/WJ4MDN) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: Maybe [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NBjMnN) is what you want, but I'm not sure because the example code isn't exactly clear to me.

Comment: @jcalz thanks, that worked! However I'm confused as to why it works, can you explain a little bit?

Comment: I'll be happy to write up an answer that explains it, if you could [edit] your example code to be a [mre] first.

Comment: I added an example, hopefully that helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an array type `T extends UseTablePlugins[]` and you want another type to evaluate to `SearchState` if `"search"` is present in the element type of `T` and `null` otherwise, then you might want to write the type like:

```
"search" extends T[number] ? SearchState : null;
```

The type `T[number]` is the element type of `T`, since it's the type you get when you [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) an array of type `T` with an index of type `number`.  Generally that will give you the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of the types of each known element type.  So if `T` is the [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) `["search", "pagination"]`, then `T[number]` is `"search" | "pagination"`.

Note that when you use a (non-[distributive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types)) [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) of the form `AAA extends BBB ? true : false`, you are going to get `true` if and only if you can assign a value of type `AAA` to a variable of type `BBB`.  You can assign a value of type `"search"` to a variable of type `"search" | "pagination"` (it's safe to widen) but not vice versa (it's unsafe to narrow).  So you need `"search" extends T[number]` and not `T[number] extends "search"` or `T extends "search"[]`, which would be more like checking if *only* `"search"` appears in the array.

---

So then `useTable()` looks something like:

```
function useTable<T extends UseTablePlugins[]>(plugins: T) {
  const searchable = plugins.includes("search");
  const searchState = searchable ? useState("") : null;
  return searchState as "search" extends T[number] ? SearchState : null;
}
```

So let's see if it works how you want.  This will depend pretty strongly on whether the compiler infers `T` narrowly enough to account for all the only the elements of the `plugins` parameter.  Here are some happy cases:

```
const okay1 = useTable(["search"]); // SearchState
const okay2 = useTable(["search", "pagination"]); // SearchState
const null1 = useTable([]); // null
const null2 = useTable(["pagination"]); // null
```

In all of those cases, the compiler infers `T` as an unordered array type where the element type is no wider nor narrower than it should be.  In the first case `T` is `Array<"search">`, and in the second it is `UseTablePlugins[]`, both of which contain `"search"` in the element type.  In the third case `T` is `never[]`, and in the fourth it is `Array<"pagination">`, neither of which contain `"search"` in the element type.

Unfortunately there are still problematic edge cases:

```
const oops1 = useTable([Math.random() < 0.99 ? "pagination" : "search"]);
// SearchState, but 99% chance it should be null at runtime
const oops2 = useTable((["search", "pagination"] as const).slice(1))
// SearchState, but definitely null at runtime
```

In both of these cases, `T` is inferred as `UseTablePlugins[]`.  The compiler knows that the elements of `plugins` are either `"pagination"` or `"search"` but it doesn't know that `"search"` will probably or definitely be absent.  This is reasonable behavior for the compiler, but it results in the return type of `useTable()` being `SearchState` instead of `null`, which is not good.  These edge cases occur because the implementation is too "optimistic" in some sense, and assumes that if `"search"` *might* be present, then it *is* present.

In general the compiler cannot know exactly which values will be in every array, so you can either err on the side of being too optimistic or too pessimistic.  If you are too pessimistic the type will never be *wrong*, but it might be too wide to be useful. This would more or less be the situation where `useTable()` returns `SearchState | null` no matter what you pass in, or at least where you get `SearchState | null` unless the compiler is positive that `"search"` is definitely present or definitely absent.  So you probably want the optimistic version, as long as you're reasonably careful to avoid the bad edge cases.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-YLRX6IBAwIQg8jQ2jMgBZChMV5QFDTKQbE6lOAABleAE5O1ynSgIq6YvzfDz3Z1PclvajsNZ8PBuwBSC73PomYDgpgQHFTOBs3O4inwKC9WogJBxsFwQvFpNl5W2iEOsL9l2ZmKcykXeNHV6EWzANA0VlI4jnUCceShGc5zgb4xHcdckFsAx91sQ8CRPUBzzUIA)

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the great explanation!